# where are my relationships lines?

Tags: objects, constraints, parent

I know that relationship lines are the dotted lines that happen when you hit the delete key on bones. I delete the bones between the spine and the legs, and my lines are not there. I read the properties menu and not only is the connected box unchecked but also grey out...did I do something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle the Relationship lines in the Overlays popover:

[image]

But they have nothing to do with you deleting bones:

> ###### Relationship Lines
>
> Show dashed lines indicating parent or constraint relationships.
>
> ---
>
> Source: **[Viewport Overlays — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html?utm_source=blender-4.0.2#bpy-types-view3doverlay-show-relationship-lines)**

If you have no relationship lines between to objects or bones, either:

1. They hare no parent nor constraint relationship
2. They do have a relationship, but there is no space between the two elements' origins to show a relationship line in.

You can see parent relationships in the Outliner:

[image]

You can also look at an object or bone's properties, in the Relations panel, it will show the parent if any, and for bones, whether it is connected or not:

[image]

Connected relationships make the child unable to move away from the parent. But unconnected ones allow moving the children away from parent, allowing for a relationship line to be displayed when there's enough space for it.

You can see constraints in the outliner. Bones with constraints are also colored differently in Pose Mode (green or yellow). You can see bones constraints when in Pose Mode only:

[image]

Other caveats the manual doesn't mention:

- Only object-level constraints have relationship lines, not bones within an armature.
- Bones show relationship lines only in Pose mode for the selected bones, or in Edit Mode regardless of selection.

Comment: funny thing...that box is checked

Comment: also how can i find out which is which?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: so how can i get them connected to form relationship lines

Comment: Enable the Connected option in Edit mode. But that will snap the bone to its parent and lock it there.